# Create iframe with javascript appending to a div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to load/append the iframe into a div with regular javascript. I can do this with JQuery without a problem, but I dont want to include the js file. I keep getting the error 'document.getElementById("ad54")' (or whatever id I assign the div). I have the following code:

```
var link = "http://www.google.com"
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder=0;
iframe.width="300px";
iframe.height="250px";
iframe.id="randomid";
iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
document.getElementById("ad54").appendChild(iframe);

<div id="ad54"></div>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should write this inside window.onload like

```
window.onload = function(){
   var link = "http://www.quirksmode.org/iframetest2.html"
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder=0;
iframe.width="300px";
iframe.height="250px";
iframe.id="randomid";
iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
document.getElementById("ad54").appendChild(iframe);

}
```

Comment: An iframe is not generated. Although, I'm no longer receiving any errors under firebug

Comment: Google.com wont be loaded in iframe . try some other link . See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: You are correct. I tried another website and it worked. Thank you for the help