# Need javascript code to run multiple times in one page. For each div

Tags: javascript, iframe, html

I forgot to include 'run multiple times in one page' on my last question located here: [Create iframe with javascript appending to a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302109/create-iframe-with-javascript-appending-to-a-div)

I need to run the code on multiple div's within the same page. Right now the code below only runs once on the last div. For example if I have 3 div's, all 3 should have an iframe appended to it. Regular javascript. Trying not to use JQuery.

```
window.onload = function(){
var link = "http://www.somesite.com"
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder=0;
iframe.width="300px";
iframe.height="250px";
iframe.id="randomid";
iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
document.getElementById("ad54").appendChild(iframe); //<--this id will be dynamically generated to match div's
}


<div class="ad" id="1"></div>
<div class="ad" id="2"></div>
<div class="ad" id="3"></div>
```

EDIT: Tested in IE9, Chrome, Safari, Firefox and opera. This code works. No JQuery or loops needed. This code will create the iframe wherever you use it.

```
var link = "http://www.somesite.com"
document.write(iframe);
var myIframe = parent.document.getElementById("randomid");
myIframe.height = 250;
myIframe.width = 300;
myIframe.src = link;
myIframe.style.border = "0px";
myIframe.style.padding = "0px";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to loop through a set of elements in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157260/whats-the-best-way-to-loop-through-a-set-of-elements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    append_iframe( elements[i] );
  }
}

function append_iframe( div ) {
    var link = "http://www.somesite.com"
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.frameBorder=0;
    iframe.width="300px";
    iframe.height="250px";
    iframe.id="randomid";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
    div.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: Still only loads the last div with an iframe

Comment: Your code was close. I just had to fiddle with it so it would load no matter how many times  I used it in a page. Thanx

Comment: Glad I helped, you can edit my answer with the working example if you wish to, that could help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a jQuery guy but I think this works

```
$("div").each(function(d) {
    var link = "http://www.somesite.com"
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.frameBorder=0;
    iframe.width="300px";
    iframe.height="250px";
    iframe.id="randomid";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
    this.appendChild(iframe);
});
```